# Triggering jobs depending on polled svn directory

Tags: svn, jenkins

I'm looking for plugin or any advice.

I have following structure of my branch on Jenkins:

```
              A (main branch)
                     |
                 ____|____
                |         |
                B         C
                |         |
           (other jobs)  (other jobs)
```

If job **A** see any changes in svn repository it is triggering **B** and **C**.

Structure of repository:

```
               A (main branch)
                     |
                 ____|____
                |         |
                B         C
```

Is there any way to trigger ONLY **B** or **C** depending where were changes?
I mean, If I commit some changes to svn's directory **B** I would like to that **A** would trigger only **B**. (Now will trigger **B** and **C**).